# Check if array index is 1 in PHP array

Tags: php

This bit of code picks up an array containing 3 indexes:

```
<?php var_dump($the_query1->posts); ?>
```

The output is an array of 3 indexes:

```
array(3) {
      [0]=>
      object(WP_Post)#4451 (24) {
        ["ID"]=>
        int(19163)
        ["post_author"]=>
        string(1) "2"
        ["post_date"]=>
        string(19) "2018-09-28 15:42:12"
        ["post_date_gmt"]=>
        string(19) "2018-09-28 13:42:12"
        ["post_content"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["post_title"]=>
        string(16) "Global Factories"
        ["post_excerpt"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["post_status"]=>
        string(7) "publish"
        ["comment_status"]=>
        string(6) "closed"
        ["ping_status"]=>
        string(6) "closed"
        ["post_password"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["post_name"]=>
        string(16) "global-factories"
        ["to_ping"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["pinged"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["post_modified"]=>
        string(19) "2018-11-15 12:41:57"
        ["post_modified_gmt"]=>
        string(19) "2018-11-15 11:41:57"
        ["post_content_filtered"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["post_parent"]=>
        int(0)
        ["guid"]=>
        string(48) "https://www.zeo.nl/?post_type=cases&p=19163"
        ["menu_order"]=>
        int(0)
        ["post_type"]=>
        string(5) "cases"
        ["post_mime_type"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["comment_count"]=>
        string(1) "0"
        ["filter"]=>
        string(3) "raw"
      }
      [1]=>
      object(WP_Post)#4448 (24) {
        ["ID"]=>
        int(19167)
        ["post_author"]=>
        string(1) "2"
        ["post_date"]=>
        string(19) "2018-09-21 14:58:50"
        ["post_date_gmt"]=>
        string(19) "2018-09-21 12:58:50"
        ["post_content"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["post_title"]=>
        string(24) "Warmteservice Groep B.V."
        ["post_excerpt"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["post_status"]=>
        string(7) "publish"
        ["comment_status"]=>
        string(6) "closed"
        ["ping_status"]=>
        string(6) "closed"
        ["post_password"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["post_name"]=>
        string(13) "warmteservice"
        ["to_ping"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["pinged"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["post_modified"]=>
        string(19) "2018-11-15 12:00:56"
        ["post_modified_gmt"]=>
        string(19) "2018-11-15 11:00:56"
        ["post_content_filtered"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["post_parent"]=>
        int(0)
        ["guid"]=>
        string(48) "https://www.zeo.nl/?post_type=cases&p=19167"
        ["menu_order"]=>
        int(0)
        ["post_type"]=>
        string(5) "cases"
        ["post_mime_type"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["comment_count"]=>
        string(1) "0"
        ["filter"]=>
        string(3) "raw"
      }
      [2]=>
      object(WP_Post)#4556 (24) {
        ["ID"]=>
        int(19157)
        ["post_author"]=>
        string(1) "2"
        ["post_date"]=>
        string(19) "2018-09-21 11:26:12"
        ["post_date_gmt"]=>
        string(19) "2018-09-21 09:26:12"
        ["post_content"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["post_title"]=>
        string(9) "Blauwtulp"
        ["post_excerpt"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["post_status"]=>
        string(7) "publish"
        ["comment_status"]=>
        string(6) "closed"
        ["ping_status"]=>
        string(6) "closed"
        ["post_password"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["post_name"]=>
        string(11) "blauwtulp-2"
        ["to_ping"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["pinged"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["post_modified"]=>
        string(19) "2018-11-15 12:46:48"
        ["post_modified_gmt"]=>
        string(19) "2018-11-15 11:46:48"
        ["post_content_filtered"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["post_parent"]=>
        int(0)
        ["guid"]=>
        string(48) "https://www.zeo.nl/?post_type=cases&p=19157"
        ["menu_order"]=>
        int(0)
        ["post_type"]=>
        string(5) "cases"
        ["post_mime_type"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["comment_count"]=>
        string(1) "0"
        ["filter"]=>
        string(3) "raw"
      }
    }
```

What is the best way to check if the current index is in position 1? I want to return a bool to decide if the element should become `<div class="col-sm-4">` or `<div class="col-sm-3">` in case true is returned.

I tried this:

```
<?php var_dump($the_query1->posts[1] === true); ?>
```

But this is returning three times `false`. I need to return `false`, `true`, `false`. What is the easiest way to do the check?

Comment: Are you just spamming your question on SO multiple times or is this a completely different problem? It sounds exactly the same as previous 2 or 3 of your questions

Comment: The last question didn't solve my problem, so I rephrased the question. Not my intention to spam.

Comment: What do you mean by *the current index is in position 1*?

Comment: where is the code you try that needs to `check if the current index`?

Comment: <?php var_dump($the_query1->posts[1] === true); ?> <- this should equate to true if the post is in the second index or rather [1]

Comment: _"so I rephrased the question"_ - You should edit the existing questions to be clear instead of writing new ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use foreach to loop your data and do a condition to match if the array key is 1.

```
foreach ($the_query1->posts as $key => $value) {
    if($key == 1){
        echo '<div class="col-sm-3">';
    } else {
        echo '<div class="col-sm-4">';
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: When I do a var_dump on $key, I get NULL. Also get NULL for $value.

Comment: Do the var_dump inside the foreach. You should be able to see the value of the key.

Comment: I did the var_dump inside the for loop, but I can't find the log anywhere in console. I've also installed WordPress PHP console, and even there, there is no log being made. Why is that?